# How to write regex for phone number that doesn't start with 0 or 1

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex

```
// 1st
export const phoneRegex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;

// 2nd
export const phoneRegex = /^\((?![0-1]})\(?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
```

My understanding of the 1st regex is that it checks that the first 3 digits are 0-9, the next 3 are 0-9 starting with a hyphen, and the final 4 are 0-9 starting with a hyphen.

We had the request to not allow the first digit to be 0 or 1. So, the 2nd regex was put in as a solution, but clearly doesn't work as it still allows the first digit to be a 0 or a 1.

Also, this regex is also checking to make sure the phone number is formatted correctly as so `(xxx)xxx-xxxx` (I think)...

GOAL

(199)912-0348 (✘) ERROR

(299)912-0348 (✔️) CORRECT

(021)231-1238 (✘) ERROR

(821)231-1238 (✔️) CORRECT

Comment: Why so complicated when one can directly put the requirements straightforward into ... [`/^\([2-9][0-9]{2}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/`](https://regex101.com/r/eub9tj/1)?

Comment: @PeterSeliger your solution doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, I see that @PeterSeliger wrote something very similar to my regex and his demo also shows that it's working. What are you not telling us about this problem since the regex _should_ work?

Comment: When I test (199) 999-9999 it passes the regex... maybe it's not considering the parentheses? @TedLyngmo

Comment: @Crystal No, neither Peter's nor my regex will match on `(199) 999-9999`. Just paste it into any of our demos to verify. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LWigtr/1). It fails on two accounts: The `1` does not match `[2-9]` and the space after `)` does not match `\d{3}`.

Comment: Okay thank you guys - so this looks like in the code I am observing the regex is correct it's something to do with Yup and Formik validation and formatting that's now allowing me to see this working.

Comment: @Crystal Great that it worked out! You're welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group it as such:

```
^\([2-9]\d{2}\)\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

- `^` - Start of line anchor
- `\(` - A literal `(`
- `[2-9]` - Any digit from 2 to 9 (inclusive)
- `\d{2}` - Two digits
- `\)` - A literal `)`
- `\d{3}` - Three digits
- `-` - A literal `-`
- `\d{4}` - Four digits
- `$` - End of line anchor

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OCaWnq/1)